# Google Tag Manager: How to trigger event when no text copy present?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to trigger events precisely when there is text copy present. In my trigger I've tried the following:

Event=Click & Target=All Elements

With the following:

```
Click text greater than 0
Click text matches regex(case insensitive) ^$
```

I've also tried creating a customer javascript variable to give the number of characters in the link text and setting this to greater than zero.

None of this worked. This feels like something that should be elementary.

How do I get a trigger to fire when link text is present OR stop a trigger when link text isn't present?

[background: if there's no link text present I'm planning to fire a tag to report the class]

**Update**

I've solved this problem with Javascript as suggested in the comments. I'll post what I used here for anyone looking, but I'll keep the question true to it's original form and seek a solution for the regex.

This was made into a variable {{CssClassPresent}}:

```
function () {
  if({{Click Classes}} != undefined && {{Click Classes}} != ""){
    return "true";
  }
}
```

You then put {{CssClassPrestn}} = true as the trigger.

Comment: I would think that a Custom Javascript variable would do it, but can you post your code for that? Also, maybe be helpful to post screenshots of your tag/trigger configurations.

Comment: Also note that using a regex of ^$ matches nothing because the end of the string (denoted by $) is where the start of the string is (denoted by ^).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you suggest using ^ alone?